# AudioContext is not a constructor error in FireFox 23

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, web-audio-api

`window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext or window.webkitAudioContext
  
@context = new AudioContext()`

This works in webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) and in the FireFox Nightly Build, but in FireFox 23, this same code gives a type error.

`AudioContext is not a constructor`

Any Ideas?

Comment: From the documentation: [AudioContext > Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext#Browser_compatibility): "Activated on Nightly only".

Answer (score 2):

if the error is this

(window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext) is not a constructor

replace this

```
var ctx = new (window.audioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
```

that is why

```
if (! window.AudioContext) {
    if (! window.webkitAudioContext) {
        bad_browser();
        return;
    }
    window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
}

var ctx = new AudioContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/07/web-audio-api-comes-to-firefox/ we might get support for the Web Audio API in normal Firefox installs as early as version 24.

According to https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases#Firefox_24 that means very soon. :D